# Access 2010 and Oracle ODBC driver: The decimal field's precision is too small

Tags: oracle, ms-access, casting, odbc, decimal

Create a table in oracle 11g:

```
create table test_table
(
  id     varchar2(10 byte),
  price  number(5,2)
)
```

Then insert a row:

```
insert into 
    test_table (id, price) 
values
    ('id_1', 99.97)
```

Then add the table to MS Access 2010 as a linked table, using the Oracle ODBC driver (mine is: file "SQLORA32.DLL", version "11.02.00.01", date 2010-03-30). If Access asks for primary keys, then select "ID" field.

Then open the table in Access (double clic on the table), to see the data. I get this error:

```
The decimal field's precision is too small to accept the numeric you attempt to add
```

Is it a bug? A bug in Access, or a bug in ODBC driver?

How can I fix it?

Comment: I would start with the latest Oracle client and latest ODBC drivers.  I use Access connected to Oracle a lot and have not seen that issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have asked for last versions to be installed in my computer (I don't have the permissions to do it). I will report the results.

Comment: @RMANExpress : Tried last version of Oracle client and ODBC driver, same result :-(. Any more ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem.  It turns out my linked table definition had decimal precision set to 5.1 when the actual Oracle table showed 8.1, a linked table refresh fixed the problem.  Basically, in Oracle the precision was increased to 8.1 but my Access linked table had not been refreshed and was not aware of the new precision setting.  Cheers, Steeve